# Playing two different instruments at the same time

Tags: sound

I have to create a sound where I need to layer the instruments. I have used pure functions like this

```
SoundNote[#, 0.1, "Violin"] & /@ {"E", "D#", "E", "D#", "E", "B", "D",
   "C", "G"}
```

And

```
SoundNote[#, 0.1, "Bass"] & /@ {"E", "D#", "E", "D#", "E", "B", "D",
   "C", "G"}
```

I want to combine them to play at the same time without having to use it like:

```
Sound[{SoundNote["E",{0,0.2},"Violin"],SoundNote["E",{0,0.2},"Bass"]}]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Table`.

```
Sound[Table[
  Sound[SoundNote[#, 0.1, inst] & /@ {"E", "D#", "E", "D#", "E", "B", "D", "C", "G"}, 
   {0, 1}], {inst, {"Violin", "Bass"}}]]
```

Note that using `Sound` on `SoundNote` for the same interval ({0,1} here) superposes both the lists. Later you could use one more `Sound` over this list of lists to achieve what you wanted.